# OpenID Connect Hybrid Flow for React Native

Tags: android, react-native, openid, openid-connect

I need to implement the hybrid code auth flow in a React Native application to authenticate with an OpenID Connect Identity Provider. Specifically, the IdP expects `code id_token` as the response type.

I used react-native-app-auth and the underlying OpenID AppAuth-Android libraries but they do not currently support this flow - see issues [#75](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/75) and [#218](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/218). They only support a single response type such as "code" or "token". Due to this, I am getting an error from the IdP saying `Unauthorized Client`. I am sending the proper scopes.

Steps I have taken so far:

1. Modify [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) source code for Android to set response type - tried giving space separated values (`code id_token`), url encoded string (`code%20id_token`), and stringified JSON array (`"['code', 'id_token']"`). This did not work.
2. Use a webview to login - I could not extract the final tokens from the web page - they are stored in the session storage and I need to take them out into the app. The process is also a bit complex with my use-case as I need to watch multiple flows after authentication and need some parameters returned in the auth response.

As a final step, I am modifying the official Android library for OpenID Connect clients - [OpenID AppAuth Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android). Will try to give that as the dependency for react-native-app-auth.

How can I implement the hybrid code flow in a React Native app? Any help is highly appreciated.